# SQL trigger to avoid duplicates with multiple IDs

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, duplicates

Good morning,

I found the solution to my problem, but I thought I'd share it anyway as it might be useful for future projects/problems. I have a simple SQL table below which will be the foreign key of my much bigger table of stock prices market data.

```
CREATE TABLE [StockMarket]
(
[ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[ReutersRIC] VARCHAR(50),
[BloombergTicker] VARCHAR(50),
[YahooSymbol] VARCHAR(50)
/* other irrelevant columns here*/
)
```

With that in mind, I am trying to add robustness to the structure as I will be adding from different data sources. For each underlying time series on the financial markets, there are multiple names depending on which data provider you use. I wanted to avoid having multiple lines with different data sources representing the same time series. I needed a trigger which:

1) If the inserted values are not yet in the table, it is simply inserted.

2) if I insert a line for which at least one [ReutersRIC], [BloombergTicker], [YahooSymbol], [ISIN] already exists, I update that specific line instead.

2.1) The update should only happen on Non-Null entrees

My question was how this can be achieved in the best possible way? It took me some time, but I wanted to share the answer below for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UniqueStockMarketInserts ON [dbo].[StockMarket]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StockId  int
    SELECT @StockId = S.ID 
        FROM [StockMarket] S INNER JOIN [INSERTED] I 
        ON
        S.YahooSymbol = I.YahooSymbol OR
        S.ReutersRIC = I.ReutersRIC OR 
        S.BloombergTicker = I.BloombergTicker OR
        S.ISIN = I.ISIN
    IF @StockId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [StockMarket] (YahooSymbol,ReutersRIC,BloombergTicker,ISIN)
        SELECT I.YahooSymbol, I.ReutersRIC, I.BloombergTicker, I.ISIN 
        FROM [INSERTED] I
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE S SET 
        S.ISIN = ISNULL(S.ISIN,I.ISIN),
        S.YahooSymbol = ISNULL(S.YahooSymbol,I.YahooSymbol),
        S.ReutersRIC = ISNULL(S.ReutersRIC,I.ReutersRIC),
        S.BloombergTicker = ISNULL(S.BloombergTicker,I.BloombergTicker)
        FROM INSERTED I, StockMarket S
        WHERE S.ID = @StockId
    END
END
GO
```

Here is the test I ran on it with real-life examples (except the ISIN which I made up):

```
/*-----------TESTING THE TRIGGER--------*/
INSERT INTO StockMarket (ReutersRIC, BloombergTicker) VALUES ('G.TO', 'GG US Equity');
INSERT INTO StockMarket (YahooSymbol, BloombergTicker, ISIN) VALUES ('GOOG', 'GOOG US Equity','US123454321');
INSERT INTO StockMarket (YahooSymbol, ISIN) VALUES ('RDSA','NL111112222')
INSERT INTO StockMarket (YahooSymbol, ReutersRIC) VALUES ('GG', 'G.TO');     /*this should update as per trigger*/
INSERT INTO StockMarket (ReutersRIC, ISIN) Values ('GOOG.OQ','US123454321'); /*this should update as per trigger*/
INSERT INTO StockMarket (YahooSymbol, ReutersRIC) Values ('RDSA', 'RDSa.L'); /*this should update as per trigger*/
```

And the results:

[image]

Hope this can help someone in the future. Happy coding